# How to cast Any which can be Realm List or String to a Realm List when applicable

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, realm

In input we have `var value: Any` which we don't control.

`value` can represent a `String` (or anything) as well as a `List<MyRealmObject>`. And it's in this Realm case that I have a question.

How can I cast the `value` (Any) to a RealmList?

My end goal is to convert this Realm List to an Array.

When I do `value as? List<Object>` I get nil.

Or in other words, I would like to avoid this non-generic code:

```
func foo(value: Any) {
    if let val = value as? List<RealmTag> {
        myArray = Array(val)
    } else if let val = value as? List<RealmUser> {
        myArray = Array(val)
    } else if let val = value as? List<RealmService> {
        myArray = Array(val)
    } etc...
}
```

Comment: Did you try value as? List<MyRealmObject>

Comment: @RobertDresler Edited my question to make it clearer, I would like to avoid cast-check the value to all the existing RealmObject I have.

Comment: I'm afraid, the only non-generic type you can cast it safely is `RLMListBase`.

Comment: @user28434 That won't help because ListBase isn't a Sequence, so I lose the information of the elements of the list and I can't convert it to an Array afterwards.

Comment: Well, it was the thing I've discovered myself too, no other type in Hierarchy will do, except `RLMListBase`. And you can convert it to `Array`, or rather copy element to new array, because `RLMListBase` supports `FastEnumeration`.